# How to get clean code for a gallery?

Tags: gallery

I want clean code for a gallery, like:

```
<div class="gallery">
<ul>
<li><a href='../wp-content/uploads/2014/04/lgitem-01.jpg'><img width="150" height="150" src="../wp-content/uploads/2014/04/lgitem-01-150x150.jpg" class="tnggallery" /></a></li>
<li><a href='../wp-content/uploads/2014/04/lgitem-01.jpg'><img width="150" height="150" src="../wp-content/uploads/2014/04/lgitem-01-150x150.jpg" class="tnggallery" /></a></li>
<li><a href='../wp-content/uploads/2014/04/lgitem-01.jpg'><img width="150" height="150" src="../wp-content/uploads/2014/04/lgitem-01-150x150.jpg" class="tnggallery" /></a></li>
<li><a href='../wp-content/uploads/2014/04/lgitem-01.jpg'><img width="150" height="150" src="../wp-content/uploads/2014/04/lgitem-01-150x150.jpg" class="tnggallery" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Currently my code is coming out like this:

```
<div id="gallery-2" class="gallery galleryid-12 gallery-columns-5 gallery-size-thumbnail"><dl class="gallery-item">
        <dt class="gallery-icon landscape">
            <a href="../uploads/2014/04/lgitem-01.jpg"><img width="150" height="150" src="../uploads/2014/04/lgitem-01-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="lgitem-01"></a>
        </dt></dl><dl class="gallery-item">
        <dt class="gallery-icon landscape">
            <a href="../uploads/2014/04/lgitem-02.jpg"><img width="150" height="150" src="../uploads/2014/04/lgitem-02-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="lgitem-02"></a>
        </dt></dl><dl class="gallery-item">
        <dt class="gallery-icon landscape">
            <a href="../uploads/2014/04/lgitem-03.jpg"><img width="150" height="150" src="../uploads/2014/04/lgitem-03-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="lgitem-03"></a>
        </dt></dl><dl class="gallery-item">
        <dt class="gallery-icon landscape">
            <a href="../uploads/2014/04/lgitem-04.jpg"><img width="150" height="150" src="../uploads/2014/04/lgitem-04-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="lgitem-04"></a>
        </dt></dl><dl class="gallery-item">
        <dt class="gallery-icon landscape">
            <a href="../uploads/2014/04/lgitem-05.jpg"><img width="150" height="150" src="../uploads/2014/04/lgitem-05-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="lgitem-05"></a>
        </dt></dl><br style="clear: both"><dl class="gallery-item">
        <dt class="gallery-icon landscape">
            <a href="../uploads/2014/04/lgitem-06.jpg"><img width="150" height="150" src="../uploads/2014/04/lgitem-06-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="lgitem-06"></a>
        </dt></dl><dl class="gallery-item">
        <dt class="gallery-icon landscape">
            <a href="../uploads/2014/04/lgitem-07.jpg"><img width="150" height="150" src="../uploads/2014/04/lgitem-07-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="lgitem-07"></a>
        </dt></dl><dl class="gallery-item">
        <dt class="gallery-icon landscape">
            <a href="../uploads/2014/04/lgitem-08.jpg"><img width="150" height="150" src="../uploads/2014/04/lgitem-08-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="lgitem-08"></a>
        </dt></dl><dl class="gallery-item">
        <dt class="gallery-icon landscape">
            <a href="../uploads/2014/04/lgitem-09.jpg"><img width="150" height="150" src="../uploads/2014/04/lgitem-09-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="lgitem-09"></a>
        </dt></dl><dl class="gallery-item">
        <dt class="gallery-icon landscape">
            <a href="../uploads/2014/04/lgitem-10.jpg"><img width="150" height="150" src="../uploads/2014/04/lgitem-10-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="lgitem-10"></a>
        </dt></dl><br style="clear: both"><dl class="gallery-item">
        <dt class="gallery-icon landscape">
            <a href="../uploads/2014/04/lgitem-11.jpg"><img width="150" height="150" src="../uploads/2014/04/lgitem-11-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="lgitem-11"></a>
        </dt></dl>
        <br style="clear: both;">
    </div>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like native gallery output. You will need to determine what is changing it (plugin/theme/etc) first.

Comment: i simpley just add gallery from admin then show like this code. no plugins installed . i don't want to use any plugins for that now. i have nextgen etc plugins have for small gallery no need actually.

Comment: Actually scratch that, this might be default — looked at wrong thing, sorry.

Comment: i already able to change most of thing from media.php page. now want to add class in <a>

Comment: finally i made it two way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to overwrite the gallery shortcode with:

```
add_shortcode( 'gallery', 'custom_gallery_shortcode' );
```

where the shortcode callback is:

```
/**
 * Overwrite the native [gallery] shortcode, to modify the HTML layout.
 */
function custom_gallery_shortcode( $attr = array(), $content = '' )
{
        $attr['itemtag']        = "li";
        $attr['icontag']        = "";
        $attr['captiontag']     = "p";

        // Run the native gallery shortcode callback:    
        $html = gallery_shortcode( $attr );

        // Remove all tags except a, img,li, p
        $html = strip_tags( $html, '<a><img><li><p>' );

        // Some trivial replacements:
        $from = array(  
            "class='gallery-item'", 
            "class='gallery-icon landscape'", 
            'class="attachment-thumbnail"',
            'a href=', 
        );              
        $to = array( 
            '',
            '',
            'class="tnggallery"', 
            'a class="lightbox" href=', 
        );
        $html = str_replace( $from, $to, $html );

        // Remove width/height attributes:
        $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", $html );

        // Wrap the output in ul tags:
        $html = sprintf( '<ul class="gallery">%s</ul>', $html );

        return $html;
}
```

to modify the HTML layout.

Comment: thank you so much.. can you tell me how to apply this. just copy and paste (changes if i need ) to function. php file or else

Comment: You can add this to your `functions.php` file in the current theme directory or create a plugin.

Comment: cool it work.. and nice too.. but i want to add class under a tag.. like <a href="Back-Double-Swing.jpg" class="lightbox">

Comment: awesome man............... thank you so much......................... i really nice.. i like this solution most . i got two but this one i feel best :) thanks again

Comment: ok great, I updated the answer. You can then modify it to your needs. If you need some additional non-trivial replacements, you might want to try for example `preg_replace()`.

Comment: humm thank you so much. again. i just one more thing if you help me see. just want to know how to remove image height and width via this code.. any way ?

Comment: add_filter('wp_get_attachment_link', 'remove_img_width_height', 10, 1);

function remove_img_width_height($html) {
    $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", $html );
    return $html;
}

this one work.. but is this perfect solution for your code ? or have any other else.

Comment: Yes you could use that. I updated the answer with the code example you provided to remve height/width attributes.

Comment: thank man.. thanks .. thank u so much for your hard work.. you are really ROCK

Comment: thanks again... i successfully use this script one my theme.. but today i got one strange problem same code same all same... not work in another theme. i tried so long but i never find out why... even tried with working theme file replace there for test. not work.. is there have server issue or worpdress setting issue ?

Comment: Maybe the gallery shortcode is also being overridden by the another theme, and thus overriding our modification?